# How to check for default DateTime value?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I need to check a `DateTime` value if it has a value or not.

I have several options:

```
if (dateTime == default(DateTime))
```

or

```
if (dateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
```

or using a nullable `DateTime?`

```
if (nullableDateTime.HasValue)
```

Personally I would prefer the third version, since its pretty good readable.
But in our database we have some datetime columns which are defined as not null.
So in some cases I have to go with the first two options.

I read somewhere that the `default` keyword should be used when working with generics, but isn't it much more readable in this case? When using the second option I have to know that the default value of a new and empty DateTime instance is DateTime.MinValue which has the smell of an implementation detail for me.

So which option should I use to use "best practice"?

Comment: In your first sentence after the code blocks, do you mean "second version", or did you mean "third version"?

Comment: Updated it ;) I meant the third version, since the property clearly explains what I intend to check: if the variable has a value

Comment: And what happens when whatever it is actually does happen at that min date?

Comment: If the database has date fields that are not null does that mean it always has valid dates in (in which case we don't need to worry) or do they use some kind of default. If the latter can you test what that default is somehow or is it inserted by the code? Nullable is certainly what you should be using here...

Comment: @Chris The bad thing is that the database is designed in the way that it has not null columns but the business logic allows invalid or default dates. So in this cases we decided to use .Net's default DateTime value to store in the db to project invalid dates. But as I described Nullable would be my favorite too, but in these cases sadly not possible.

Comment: Who designed the database?  Have you fed back to whoever maintains the overall system that the field in question should be nullable?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I would probably make this really explicit:

```
// Or private, or maybe even public
internal static readonly DateTime MagicValueForNullDateTimeInNonNullableColumns
    = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Okay, so I'd make the name *slightly* less wordy, but you get what I mean. It doesn't really matter much how you initialize that value - it's clear what you're trying to do.

(Of course, use a nullable type any time you can for this. I'm assuming the question was asked because you *couldn't* do so in certain situations.)

Comment: For MY context (not able to adapt database to support nullable datetime columns) I unfortunately need to go without Nullable. So your suggestion is most acceptable, cause by making this explicit the business rule behind the check can be realized easier. I will go this way. Accepted it, thanks!

Comment: @dasheddot: I would also put this logic in your data layer and convert to a Nullable<DateTime> as appropriate so that your code everywhere else will use nice code and you only ever have to use the above check once.

Answer (score 20):

> I need to check a `DateTime` value if it has a value or not.

You've pretty-much described the textbook situation requiring a `Nullable<DateTime>`. I'd go with that option.

(You'd obviously need some sort of translation layer if you need to persist the values to a non-null db column, but I'd try to keep any "magic" value as close to the db as possible, and try to keep your C# code clean and idiomatic.)

Answer (score 9):

The "best" practice would be using the nullable `DateTime`. Nullable value types were created *exactly* for that reason of not trusting "magic" numbers.

What's most important about this approach is its intent - what does it *mean* in your context to have a "default" date/time?

Comment: In my context it would really mean that there was no date defined by user which is valid from the business rules sight. So I guess Nullable would be best, but unfortunately I cannot adapt the database, which let me stick to the first two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set a default value in your database with getdate() and then update all null values to min value or whatever you like. At least you will have one condition